# Problems with Expressions in C

Tags: c, expression

I have two functions written that have simple assignment statements with very simple expressions. The expressions are the same for both functions, however, they involve different variable types: One function uses an array of structs, the other just uses a typedef'd struct.

When running the functions, the second function fails to divide by 256, and I get very high values that are not "normalized". I have to uncomment the second line in the second function (valueB = valueB / 256) to get it to work.

The first function, however, works perfectly.

Heres the statement in Function One:

```
value = ((p[0].value * p2Area)+(p[1].value * p3Area)+(p[2].value * p0Area)+(p[3].value * p1Area) / 256);
```

Heres the statement in Function Two:

```
valueB = ((dataPoints.p0B * p2Area)+(dataPoints.p1B * p3Area)+(dataPoints.p2B * p0Area)+(dataPoints.p3B * p1Area) / 256);
        //valueB = valueB / 256;
```

Why would this happen?

Also, I pass the functions the same numbers and it doesn't seem to help.

This is on MacOSX 10.6.8, inside Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: What are the types of these variables? What are the types of the values used in the expressions? What is this code supposed to be doing? Give us some more information and it will be much easier for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: I am surprised the first one works `... (p[2].value * p0Area)+(p[3].value * p1Area) / 256);` suggests that `(p[3].value * p1Area)` is the only part divided by 256. I would think you would add them all up and divide by 256

Comment: Going to guess Michael is right on that one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages try sliding the 256 outside the parentheses (on both equations).

Comment: First of all, thank you all for chipping in to help! Adding the extra set of parenthesis around (((a+b)(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)) / 256) fixed the issue. But, how did the first function work at all? Also, additional info: The 256 number is the total area of all the other areas (p0Area - p3Area) together. These statements are part of a bilinear interpolation function. The values of the p[x].value and dataPoints.pxB are random values between 0 and 256 as well, although they could be anything else as well, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Are you absolutely sure the first one works properly? You have

```
value = ((p[0].value * p2Area)+(p[1].value * p3Area)+(p[2].value * p0Area)+(p[3].value * p1Area) / 256);
```

I think you want:

```
value = (((p[0].value * p2Area)+(p[1].value * p3Area)+(p[2].value * p0Area)+(p[3].value * p1Area)) / 256);
```

Similar thing with the second. I think it should be:

```
value = (((p[0].value * p2Area)+(p[1].value * p3Area)+(p[2].value * p0Area)+(p[3].value * p1Area)) / 256);
```

In both cases I think you want to divide the sum of the products by 256. Not just the last one. My change only involves placing an extra set of parentheses around the sum of the product subexpressions and dividing the entire thing by 256

In all languages there is an order by which mathematical (and all other operators are completed). It just so happens that * and / are higher in precedence than + and - in C/C++ You may refer to this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) for more details.

To simplify what happened to you, I will create this simple equation:

```
 2 + 4 + 6 + 4 / 2
```

Since division occurs first (and there are no parentheses to alter the order) it gets computed as:

```
 2 + 4 + 6 + (4 / 2) = 14
```

Not:

```
 (2 + 4 + 6 + 4) / 2 = 8
```

So my change to your code was the same as putting parentheses around `2 + 4 + 6 + 4 / 2` giving `(2 + 4 + 6 + 4) / 2` and forcing the division to be done last after all the additions are completed.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean. I can assure you that the first function works great, however after your explanation, I can't explain why.

Comment: I'm not the greatest at math (clearly), I always forget the order of operations all the time. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for asking such a n00b question also, and taking you're time. I was really tripped up by the first function working. The first function was a rewrite from a previous implementation. I also have an odd suspicion that sometimes, certain parts of my code isn't compiled after it is changed, and previous symbols/code generated are somehow kept the same, but new when new functions/code are added, they are thrown in. Is this possible, or should I quit babbling?

Comment: Oh nothing wrong with your question. Operator precedence causes a lot of grief for programmers who are relatively new. It is possible for things not to get rebuilt but using XCode it is generally pretty good about knowing what needs updating. I am curious if you were actually able to solve this problem?